# How to get number of weeks in a string date

Tags: android

How to get the number of weeks in a month and the number of week of a date in a month if i have a string date which is like this "04/06/2019 5:11:37 PM", "09/03/2019 10:47:43 PM", "17/01/2019 1:36:39 AM".

For eg, 09/03/2019. 
Number of weeks in March is: x
09 in March is in Week: x

Comment: What is the actual value for number of weeks for `09/03/2019` which you are expecting?

Comment: if you give the input -> 09/03/2019  whats the output? number of weeks in march = 4 this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of weeks in a month for a sample date like `09/03/2019` as you've mentioned, you can use this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
int numberOfWeeks = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

first include your input format

```
String input = "2019/03/09";
String format = "yyyyMMdd";

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = df.parse(input);
// you can parse it as Calendar object

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```